# bootstrap's switch + AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Before I get any down-marking, please bear in mind that I'm relatively new to this whole web application development thing, so please go easy on me!
My problem is that i can not seem to bind the bootstrap "switch" to a js function that sends an AJAX request, to update a record in the database.

here's my attempt:

1. the JS:

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-switch/3.3.4/js/bootstrap-switch.js" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(e){
  var stopchange = false;
  $('.switch-input').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (e, state) {
   var obj = $(this);
   var arr = e.split("_");
   var appid = arr[1];
   var owaspid = arr[2];
   if(stopchange === false){
    $.ajax({
     method: 'POST',
     url: 'actions.php',
     data: {
     val: value,
     user: '<?php echo $_SESSION['user'] ?>',
     app: appid,
     owasp: owasp,
     action: "update_worklog"
     },
     success: function(result) {
      if(result['done'] == true) {
       alert('Status changed successfully.');
      } else {
       alert('Error:'+result['message']);
       if(stopchange === false){
        stopchange = true;
        obj.bootstrapSwitch('toggleState');
        stopchange = false;
       }
      }
     },
     error: function(result) {
      alert('Error! Unable to update progress.');
      if(stopchange === false){
       stopchange = true;
       obj.bootstrapSwitch('toggleState');
       stopchange = false;
      }
     }
    });
   }
  });
 });
</script>
</head>
```

2. The switch:

> Note: The $v->checked statement derives from a json that is parsed
>   beforehand

```html
echo '<td><label class="switch switch-text switch-primary"><input id="check_' . $SomeID. '_' . $v->name . '" name="ncheck_' . $SomeID . '_' . $v->name . '" type="checkbox" class="switch-input"';
if($v->checked == "True") {
 echo "checked";
}
echo '><span data-on="✓" data-off="×" class="switch-label"></span> <span class="switch-handle"></span></label></td>';
```

for the record: i've been through a lot of the similar issues in stackoverflow (such as : [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474015/bootstrap-switch-toggle-function-with-jquery-and-ajax?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474015/bootstrap-switch-toggle-function-with-jquery-and-ajax?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474015/bootstrap-switch-toggle-function-with-jquery-and-ajax?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) ) but i just can't seem to get this thing to work properly.
if you have any comments/ideas/possible solutions, please don't hold back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too have came across such issue.I think this should solve your problem

```
$("input.switch-input").on('change.bootstrapSwitch', function(e){

    if($(this).is(':checked'))
        alert('checked');
    else
        alert('not checked');

    //code..

    $.ajax({
           //code..
                success: function(result) {
                    if(result['done'] == true) {
                        alert('Status changed successfully.');
                    } else {
                        alert('Error:'+result['message']);
                        if(stopchange === false){
                            stopchange = true;
                            $(this).bootstrapSwitch('toggleState');
                            stopchange = false;
                        }
                    }
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    alert('Error! Unable to update progress.');
                    if(stopchange === false){
                        stopchange = true;
                        $(this).bootstrapSwitch('toggleState');
                        stopchange = false;
                    }
                }

    });

});
```

Comment: Works like a charm! thank you very-very much! @Viney